# Bulma table rows not spanning full width

Tags: css, angular, bulma

I have a `is-fullwidth` Bulma table in my angular7 app which works fine. But now I need to add a angular component inside each row, and `td` tags lies inside that component. But when I do that, table rows not spans to its full width.

```html
<table class="table is-fullwidth">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <app-table-row [details]="row">
      </app-table-row>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### table-row.component.html

```html
<td>
  <div *ngIf="!showField"> {{ details.name }} </div>
  <div *ngIf="showField" class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <input [value]="details.name" class="input" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>{{ details.address }}</td>
```

This outputs the following
[image: output image]

if I remove the angular component and add `td`s normally, it spans correctly. Like this.
[image: correct image]

Why is it not work when angular component added? And how should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is probably because the `td` elements are not direct children of the `tr`, but children of the `app-table-row` component.

Not sure that it would make sense in your case, but you can change the selector property in the `app-table-row` component to select the `tr` itself, like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tr[app-table-row]',
    ...
})
export class AppTableRowComponent  {}
```

And use it like this:

```
<table class="table is-fullwidth">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows" app-table-row [details]="row">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way the `app-table-row` is not a separate node in the DOM.